# Android: sqlite querying based on username

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public ArrayList < PatientInfo > getAllPatients(String username) {
    ArrayList < PatientInfo > patients = new ArrayList < PatientInfo > ();

    open();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(UserTable, null, null, null, null, null, AccessedDate);
    while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Log.e("XXX", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
    close();

    Collections.reverse(patients);
    return patients;
}
```

I am getting username as argument in my method, how can i query out my table based on username and get the `user specific result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [the documentation](http://goo.gl/Lrr02), the third and fourth parameters to `query()` are the selection and selection args.

So you want something like this:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query(UserTable, null, 
                          "username=?", new String[] {username}, 
                          null, null, AccessedDate);
```

Edit the third parameter as needed to match the actual name of the relevant column in your table.